# Slow boot in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: boot, 18.10

I run dual boot. I am facing a slow boot in Ubuntu 18.10. I tried some tricks by searching, but nothing happened.

`sudo systemd-analyze time` gives following output:

```
Startup finished in 2.949s (firmware) + 4.010s (loader) + 6.866s (kernel) + 58.435.828s (userspace) = 1min 12.262s  
graphical.target reached after 1min 58.418s in userspace
```

and this is my *etc/fstab* file

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=602d217d-9099-4933-b1da-430772933e66 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=8EF1-FB7D  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
# /dev/disk/by-uuid/0DBD0F870DBD0F87 /mnt/0DBD0F870DBD0F87 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,ro 0 0
# /dev/disk/by-uuid/5640669640667C9D /mnt/Movies\040and\040Videos auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,ro 0 0
# /dev/disk/by-uuid/368C89D98C899451 /mnt/others auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,ro 0 0
```

**Note** : I commented out the last 3 lines

This is `systemd-analyze blame` command's output:

[image]

Comment: Please use text for the outputs of the command.

Comment: As the text content of pictures cannot be searched, please use copy-paste of text to show the output of commands...  **;-)**